# How is the final price calculated when group prices are used?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, catalog

I am facing a problem regarding prices per group in magento.
I'm using version 1.7.0.2, occurs in a manner to be expected that I put a lower value to any customer group, but if I put a value above it ignores, or takes the original.

I will try to exemplify:

### **1. Case 1: (functional)**

The value of my Product is **20:00**;
   Group on Price to have a certain group value **10.00**;
   In this case it works normally.

### **2. Case2:**

The value of my Product is **20:00**;
   Group on Price to have a group value of **30.00**;
No longer works as expected, he'll take the "30.00"  20.00 as meaning he does not interpret the rule groups.

Could someone help me understand what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All kinds of specialprices are ment for discounts only. Magento takes the lowest price after evaluation all discount types. This includes special prices, tier prices or catalogrules for examples. See `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::calculatePrice` for further reference.

Comment: I see ... Is there any way around this?

Comment: There are modules available for defining a surcharge. Or you could write your own one. What is the purpose of your surcharge?

Comment: Purpose would be the end product would have a base price, and each of your group, but the base price may be lower or higher, depends on the case.

Comment: I don't know such a module. It would have to change many core magento features. As mentioned above many factors have to be taken into account for price calculation. Not mentioning indexing and pricemodels per product type. Maybe you get lucky with the magento way of group prices or you could use different prices per website.

Comment: I found this module, giving a quick look you think that is feasible?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-group-prices.html

Comment: Can't tell without seeing the code. Check out their demo if it fits your needs. Compared to contracting someone to program it for you it's still low priced.